# Does crashlytics have a public API?

Tags: android, c++, ios, mobile, crashlytics

we are currently evaluating the integration of crash trackers for a mobile app that is developed in cross-platform style using c++ (and Unreal engine 4 to be specific).

The two possible candidates are crashlytics and hockeyapp.
While hockeyapp is exposing a REST Api to send crashes (see http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-crashes#post-custom-crashes), we cannot find something similar for crashlytics.
We would prefer such a custom REST-solution, because the integration of crashlytics only seems to be easy for Android apps using Java and iOs apps using Objective-C.

Is there any way to send custom crashes to crashlytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Crashlytics has no API to post custom crash results. But, the SDK may let you log custom data.

Answer (score 1):

As Webo80 said, you can use custom Logs in Crashlytics

> At times, even full stack traces with line numbers aren't quite enough to pinpoint the bug. To give you even more insight, Crashlytics provides 4 logging mechanisms right out of the box: **Logging, Custom Keys, User Information, and Caught Exceptions**.

visit [Crashlytics Custom Log](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/120055-how-do-i-use-custom-keys)